# Variadic char array shows up incorrectly in nested function C++

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions, variadic

I have two functions for a windows wrapper class, through which Im trying to pass a variadic argument list of char* arrays

The first one is:

```
bool OsInterface::AddDropdown(std::string menu_item_name, RECT v_location, int num_entries, ...)
{
    bool ret_val = true;
    va_list v_args;
    va_start(v_args, num_entries);
    //char* item_name = va_arg(v_args, char*);
    if (!windowCreator.AddDropdown(menu_item_name, v_location, num_entries, v_args))
        ret_val = false;
    va_end(v_args);
    return ret_val;
}
```

The second one is

```
bool WindowCreator::AddDropdown(std::string drop_down_name, RECT v_location, int num_entries, ...)
{
    va_list v_args;
    va_start(v_args, num_entries);
    std::vector<std::string> item_names;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_entries; i++)
    {
        char* item_name = va_arg(v_args, char*);
        item_names.push_back(item_name);
    }
    va_end(v_args);
    //Unrelated code following    
}
```

and I'm calling it this way:

```
if (!osInterface.AddDropdown("Menu_Dropdown", v_position, 1, "Item1"))
```

Here is the problem:

When I uncomment the line in the first function:
`char* item_name = va_arg(v_args, char*);`

I can see that item_name is in fact **"Item1"**

However, when I do the same thing in the second function, it `item_name` points to a completely different memory location and I get some garbage like this: **"\Ú±"**

Note that I still have the same line commented in the first function when I do this.

How do I correctly pass a variadic argument char array or string to a nested function?

Edit: I understand that these are not technically nested functions because function 2 is not defined within function 1, I couldn't find a better term to use for it

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect

```
bool WindowCreator::AddDropdown(std::string drop_down_name, RECT v_location, 
                                int num_entries, ...) {
    ... va_start ...
    ... va_arg ...
    ... va_end ...
}
```

This is correct

```
bool WindowCreator::AddDropdown(std::string drop_down_name, RECT v_location, 
                                int num_entries, va_list v_args) {
    // no va_start
    ... va_arg ...
    // no va_end
}
```

See [vprintf and friends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf).

Having said that, consider dropping the C baggage and passing an [`std::initializer_list<std::string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) rather than dealing with varargs.